# How to prevent ui-select from being closed when selecting items (with multiple select)?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I don't want to close `ui-select dropdown (with multiple select)` when I select any value. I will close is on clicking outside of the drop down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `close-on-select` attribute to false, as shown in [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select).

Example:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selected" close-on-select="false">
```

You can find a live example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1lkZ5uE2UTTifFoI82Io?p=preview).